# Port apps developed in Windows Phone 8.1 to run on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing app for Windows Phone 8.1. Will I be able to port it to run on Windows Phone 8?

Comment: As Łukasz Rejman has pointed out you cannot. (at least not with much effort) WP8 uses only "xap" files, but it does work the other way around; the WP8.1 OS supports both "xap" and "appx" files. But the drawback is that some screen resolutions run in compatibility support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Windows Phone 8 apps use Silverlight while Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal) apps use WinRT.